# MongoDB : How do I update String :List of String data in MongoDB using python?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql

```
x = mycol.insert_one({
    "name":List_Name.keys(),
    "time": List_Name.values()**strong text**``
})

tried this doesnt work`x = mycol.insert_one({
"name":List_Name.keys(),
"time": List_Name.values()
})
```

`List_Name` is a dictionary.
New to mongo
It says-

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: dict_keys(['Pushpraj']), of type: <class 'dict_keys'>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry new to stackOverflow for asking question...did attach deatils but question was not getting posted so had to shorten it...but got the working answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `keys()` method returns a `<class 'dict_keys'>` object, you need to cast it to a string like so:

```
separator = ", "
list_of_names = separator.join(List_Names.keys()) # keys separated by comma and space

x = mycol.insert_one({
    "name":list_of_names,
})
```